# Retornar valores de elementos sem determinada classe

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho uma lista com imagens, e preciso retornar um valor dessas imagens para depois atribuir alguns comandos. O problema é que em algumas `<li>` haverá uma classe chamada `off` e precisa ser "descartada" da ordem.

Código exemplificando:

```
<ul>
    <li class="off">
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="imgx" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="imgx" />
    </li>
    <li class="off">
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="imgx" />
    </li>
    <li class="off">
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="imgx" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="imgx" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Ou seja, eu preciso listar as `<img>` que não estão dentro da `<li class="off">`.

Eu tentei algo do tipo:

```
var teste = $('li:not(:has(.off)) > img.imgx').eq(1).attr('src');
```

Mas parece que não está "excluindo" as com classe `off`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usei o seletor `li:not(.off) > img.imgx` que seleciona todos os elementos com classe `imgx` cujo pai seja um `li` que não tenha a classe `off`.

O problema que você teve é devido ao acumulo de dois pseudo-seletores, que não é necessário nesse caso.

No exemplo abaixo, para ilustrar, eu adiciono uma classe `selecionad` para destacar o resultado do seletor.

```js
$('li:not(.off) > img.imgx').addClass('selecionado');
```

```css
.selecionado {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="off">
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="imgx" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="imgx" />
    </li>
    <li class="off">
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="imgx" />
    </li>
    <li class="off">
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="imgx" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="imgx" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Resolvido! Troquei para apenas `:not( )` e funcionou! Muito obrigado :D